# How to get Prettier working with js files in vim?

Tags: javascript, vim, vi, prettier

I followed https://github.com/prettier/vim-prettier instructions and added

```
// @format
```

at the top of my `.js` files.

I installed prettier with

```
cd ~/.vim/bundle/
git clone https://github.com/prettier/vim-prettier
```

but I can't see to get Prettier to work, either on file save or by using `:Prettier` at the ex command line. Nothing changes

At the command line, when I run

```
$ npx prettier-eslint $PWD/'**/*.js'
```

I get newly formatted output as expected.

```
package.json
```

includes

```
"devDependencies": {
  "eslint": "^6.8.0",
  "eslint-plugin-jest": "^23.6.0",
  "jest": "^25.1.0",
  "prettier-eslint-cli": "^5.0.0"
```

Answer (score 2):

IF you are manually installing the prettier plugin then you have missed one step

what you will have to do is

1. `cd ~/.vim/bundle/`
2. `git clone https://github.com/prettier/vim-prettier`
3. `cd vim-prettier` cd inside prettier root directory and do `yarn install` or `npm install`

the third step is important because you don't have prettier executable globally or in your project installed and I see in your question you have missed that step

And if you don't have prettier in your project ( in which you are running the format command ) or in `vim-prettier` directory or globally installed you can specify prettier executable `let g:prettier#exec_cmd_path = "~/path/to/cli/prettier"`

**Also note** that i was using `branch release/1.x` not the master for stability